# Date format returning as M/d/yyyy instead MM/dd/yyyy c#

Tags: c#, date-formatting

I was using below code to get ShortDatePattern format in c#

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
```

Which returns me as "M/d/yyyy" however i am expecting "MM/dd/yyyy" as its US date format. Why i am getting 1st format instead 2nd?

Answer (score 8):

This is machine dependant. You set this in the control panel on your computer, and `M/d/yyyy` is the default. While you *could* change this to match, you can't rely on other computers having the same settings and you really should not assume other users will be happy with your setting choice. If you need a specific format, ask for that specific format.

[image: Time Format]

Comment: Okay Thanks for reply. If you look at code snippet that i have given is not talking about current thread however its specific. I will get whatever i set using current thread however in mentioned scenario its not.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ShortDatePattern. By default is M/d/yyyy

Below is an example

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat;
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1);
      Console.WriteLine("Original Short Date Pattern:");
      Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", dtfi.ShortDatePattern, 
                                       date1.ToString("d", dtfi));
      dtfi.DateSeparator = "-";
      dtfi.ShortDatePattern = @"yyyy/MM/dd";
      Console.WriteLine("Revised Short Date Pattern:");
      Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", dtfi.ShortDatePattern, 
                                       date1.ToString("d", dtfi));

// The example displays the following output:
//       Original Short Date Pattern:
//          M/d/yyyy: 5/1/2011
//       Revised Short Date Pattern:
//          yyyy/MM/dd: 2011-05-01
```